# How to grep for all packages used in a tex file

Tags: latex, grep

Assuming I want to `grep` all packages used in a tex file:

```
$ grep usepackage my.tex
```

will do, with (as far as I can see) one exception: If a package gets loaded with that many options that the author of the file decided to insert line breaks, as in

```
\usepackage[option1,
option2,
option3]{thepackage}
```

Would there be a way to tell grep to continue parsing the file until it hits the `}`?

Ideally I would only get the `thepackage` as output, so that I could possibly iterate over it, such as:

```
$ for i in `locate `my grep command`.sty`
do
grep \\\\newcommand{\\\\createstrouble} $i
done
```

in order to quickly find a package in which a command `\createstrouble` is defined?

EDIT: One further complication: I have a `\usepackage` command as follows:

```
\usepackage[pdftitle={My Title},
 pdfauthor={My Author}]{hyperref}
```

EDIT: I understood that this approach doesn't work for my purpose, which was to find out conflicting packages. Primarily so, because a package loaded by `\usepackage{something}` pulls in more packages through `RequirePackage` which one will not have on ones radar. Better to work with the logfile, possibly using `\listfiles` in ones preamble, producing a list of files loaded, and grepping through ones `texmf` directory for the actual command name used by different packages.

Comment: check `pcregrep` with a multi line example explained in an answer over [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686147/how-to-find-patterns-across-multiple-lines-using-grep)

Comment: My approach would be to convert the latex to plain text first and then user grep. Related link http://stackoverflow.com/q/530121

Answer (score 2):

You can do multiline matches in regular grep using a combination of the `-P` (PCRE mode) and `-z` flags e.g.

```
grep -zP '(?s)\\usepackage.+?}' file
```

or with `pcregrep`

```
pcregrep -M '(?s)\\usepackage.+?}' file
```

The `(?s)` modifier allows `.` to match newlines.

---

To get just the package name, you could try either

```
grep -zPo '(?s)\\usepackage.*?{\K.+?(?=})' file
```

or

```
pcregrep -Mo '(?s)\\usepackage.*?{\K.+?(?=})' file
```

Testing the plain grep expression on a TeX manuscript of my own I get the following package list:

```
~$ grep -zPo '(?s)\\usepackage.*?{\K.+?(?=})' myfile.tex
geometry
changepage
inputenc
textcomp,marvosym
fixltx2e
amsmath,amssymb
cite
nameref,hyperref
lineno
microtype
rotating
setspace
caption
lastpage,fancyhdr,graphicx
epstopdf
```

Comment: Now that I can actually try the commands you're suggesting it seems that none of them are doing what they should: Both the plain `grep` commands give me just a `Binary file xxx.tex matches` output, the first pcregrep has a similar output like `grep usepackage xxx.tex` and the second pcregrep example 20 times prints `document`, possibly from the first line of my file which starts with `documentclass`.

Comment: I should add though, which complicates things a bit further, that the ` \usepackage` command which spans several line has within it's option two more groups of curly braces, namely `\usepackage[pdftitle={My Title}, pdfauthor={My Author}]{hyperref}`.

Comment: @muk.li I think the failure of the last two expressions may have been due to the greediness of the matches - please see the edited expressions which I have tested on a .tex file of my own

Comment: Weird. I just get a `Binary file xxx.tex matches`.

Comment: If I add the --text option to grep it almost works, but some problems remain. I guess one would have to tell grep to ignore everything in square brackets after the `\usepackage`, even if there's a line break, and resume only at the opening curly brace **after** the square brackets.

Comment: Also the case of `\usepackage{packagea,packageb}` needs to be considered.

Comment: @muk.li yes it will be up to you to craft an appropriate regular expression for more complex cases: I am not an expert in the complete syntax specification of the `\usepackage` command (although I think the `usepackage{packagea,packageb}` case is already covered based on my test output). Why grep is identifying your tex files as binary is another question, I think.

Comment: Yes, this is getting quite complex I'm afraid. A normal `grep` without further options processes my file as a normal text file, it treats it as binary when I use the `-z` option, which in the manpage curiously comes right after `-U, --binary`.

Answer (score 2):

It's not simple to write a TeX parser. Therefore the following solution can only be try.

Using `awk` twice and `uniq`

```
awk '/usepackage/,/}$/ {gsub(/\\/,"\n",$0);printf "%s",$0}' my.tex |\
awk -F{ '{gsub(/}/,"",$NF); if ($NF != "") {print $NF}}' |\
sort -u
```

---

*Example*

```
$ cat foo.tex
\usepackage[pdftitle={My Title},
 pdfauthor={My Author}]{hyperref}
\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage[scale=0.85]{geometry}

$ awk '/usepackage/,/}$/ {gsub(/\\/,"\n",$0);printf "%s",$0}' foo.tex |\
  awk -F{ '{gsub(/}/,"",$NF); if ($NF != "") {print $NF}}' |\
  sort -u
geometry
hyperref
ngerman
```

Comment: Doesn't quite work yet, see my edit above.  There are groups of curly braces within the package options. And it would really be nice to just get the package names.

Comment: @muk.li answer updated

Comment: `sort | uniq` can be done in one step as `sort -u`.

Comment: @StefanMajewsky Thx, updated